# After ajax reload, query cannot get id from url

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I create a button with ajax, when I click the button it will make an ajax request which executes a php file. The problem is I need to pass the URL Id into the php page in order to continue the query. When ajax reloads it just refreshes the div only so the system cannot get the ID.

Is there any solution to pass the ID into ajax side.

Here is the javascript

```js
$('.like-btn').on('click',function(){
    var postID = $(this).attr("id");
    var user_id = $("#userID").val();
    var theclass = $(this).attr("class");
    var act= '';
    var tempScrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
    if($(this).hasClass("like-h"))
    {
        act = 'unlike';
    }
    else if($(this).hasClass("unlike-h"))
    {
        act = 'like';
    }
    else
    {
        act = 'like';
    }
    $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url:"ajax/likeajax.php",
        data: {'act':act,'postID':postID,'uid':user_id},
        success: function(data){
            $("#viewprofile").load("viewviewprofile.php");
            $("#puid").val(data);
            $(window).scrollTop(tempScrollTop);
        }
    });
```

I cannot get the id with

```
$puid= $_GET['clickuid'];
```

This is the query

```
$puid = $_GET['clickuid'];
$query = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM status WHERE uid=$puid ORDER BY date DESC ");
```

Comment: There are some already data sent via post like act,uid,postId. You can send this clickuid with them. Or you want to send it via GET method only ?

Comment: Are you looking for the 'clickuid' property in the first script `likeajax.php` or in the `viewviewprofile.php` script? Which file is that PHP code from?

Answer (score 1):

2 things:

1) You are using `POST` and trying to access `GET` (either change your `type` to `GET` or change `$_GET` in php to `$_POST`)

2) You're not passing the `clickuid` param